# How to print user input to the console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I am trying to test if the server is being send the input of a user. How do I print the input to the console?

Right now the console.log is printing the message "About to create new room", but I need the input as well.

Client-side:

```
// Creating new room
    $("#createNewRoom").click(function(){
      var roomName = $("#createNewRoom").val();
      if ($('#NamingRoom').val().trim() == "") {
        return;
      } else {
            socket.emit("CreateNewRoom", $NamingRoom.val());
            $("#NamingRoom").val("");
            $("#NewRoomWindow").hide();
      }
    });
```

Server-side:

```
// Creating new room

client.on("CreateNewRoom", function(roomName){
    console.log("About to create new room");
    rooms = roomName;
    socket.sockets.emit("update-rooms", rooms);
});
```

Comment: You want to know how to print out the input in the `console.log`?

Comment: I think you're asking about writing the incoming socket message to console, but I'm not certain.  In that case simply write it in the listener:

client.on("CreateNewRoom", function(roomName){
    console.log("About to create new room", roomName);
    rooms = roomName;.
    socket.sockets.emit("update-rooms", rooms);
});

Comment: Yes. I know how to print a message to the console, but I need the input

Comment: @JonasSH, Can't get your point, `CreateRoom` function will only create a room and will emit an event to others stating the a new room is credited. Where the user input comes into picture here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply include the `roomName` variable within your `console.log`:

```
console.log("About to create new room", roomName);
```

This will cause the console to log something like:

> About to create new room *room name*

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: shouldn't it be `console.log("About to create new room: " + roomName);`?

Comment: @KingReload you can do that as well if you'd prefer. `console.log("About to create new room: " + roomName)` and `console.log("About to create new room:", roomName)` will both output the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for